# MariaDB on HomeBrew: Enabling Network Access

Tags: macos, mariadb, homebrew, my.cnf

I have just installed MariaDB 10.4 using Home Brew. I was finally able to set the root password, and I am now trying to enable network access.

I *think* have added the correct directive:

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

The thing is, is it to the correct `my.cnf`? I have tried adding it to `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` as well as to a `my.cnf` I found in various Cellar directories.

It doesn’t seem to work. I get the message

```
Host … is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server
```

even when I try from the local machine.

Am I setting the directive in the wrong file, or is there something else I should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your user have the privilege to access the database from remote by running:

```
SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user
```

Check also that you don't have the [`skip_networking`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#skip_networking) configuration property set.

Read also the following documentation page: [Configuring MariaDB for Remote Client Access](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/)